# Macro to Split Excel Data into into Existing Tabs

Tags: excel, csv, vba

thanks for looking at this problem, I hope I can get some help, as I am not very experienced with VBA syntax in excel.

Background:
I will be receiving a large (1000's of lines) CSV file that will contain data entries of various lengths. Each line will begin with a code (eg, 01, 02,..., 50) and have a series of data entries following it based on that code.
So, for example

01,data,data,data

01,data,data,data

02,data,data,data,data

etc...

I need to import all of this data into an existing excel workbook that already has separate tabs and headers created to correspond with the data type.

What I believe needs to be done, is to import the csv to a new, blank sheet, then run a vba program to check the data code, and move the line to the corresponding tab. I would also like to preserve the formatting on the destination sheet.

Ultimately, what I think I need is a VBA program to read the code cell, and move the line to an existing tab based on that code, and loop through the whole column.

Most of the existing solutions I have found involve the creation of new tabs, but I wish to parse the raw data into existing tabs with headers and formatting. I am aware this may require me to manually type in the code and destination tab names in the program's logic - That will not be an issue as long as I have a base to start with!

Thanks again for your help, and let me know if I can provide any more information.

Comment: **[This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618531/is-this-simple-to-copy-pasting-rows-with-excel-vba)** should give you a starting point.

Comment: Are the tab (worksheet) names exactly the same as the data type names? Do the headers on each worksheet appear in the same order as the data items for the corresponding data type appear in the CSV file?

Comment: No, the tab names do not correspond exactly to the data type names.
This is where I figure I will have to type in the destination names manually, but that is only a minor inconvenience.
The headers on each worksheet do appear in the same order as the data items for the corresponding data types.